# How to check a condition before publishing a post (Wordpress - Hooks)

Tags: wordpress

I want to check a condition before a user can post something. The user must have a jeton (user metadata), if not, the post will not be pushed in the database, else, it will and one jeton will be burn. What is the hook or filter I'm looking for ?

```
/* Jeton is French for token or coin */

add_action('what_is_the_action_or_filter_im_looking_for', 'check_jeton_before_publish');

function check_jeton_before_publish($data) {

    $user_id = get_current_user_id(); // Get user ID
    $meta_jeton = get_user_meta($user_id, 'jeton'); // Jeton count

    if ($meta_jeton == 0 || empty($meta_jeton)) { // No jeton ? No post !

        return;

    } else { // Jeton ? Post, then burn one jeton

        $new_jeton_count = $meta_jeton - 1;
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'jeton', $new_jeton_count);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your precious time !

Comment: I think the [save_post action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: @cabrerahector the documentation said "Fires once a post has been saved." I think it's not what I'm looking for since I'm looking to check a condition before a post is saved and if the condition is not met want to cancel. Thanks for the answer I'll check this further.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wp_post_insert](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) the filter wp_insert_post_empty_content should work for you.

```
   /**
     * Filters whether the post should be considered "empty".
     *
     * The post is considered "empty" if both:
     * 1. The post type supports the title, editor, and excerpt fields
     * 2. The title, editor, and excerpt fields are all empty
     *
     * Returning a truthy value to the filter will effectively short-circuit
     * the new post being inserted, returning 0. If $wp_error is true, a WP_Error
     * will be returned instead.
     *
     * @since 3.3.0
     *
     * @param bool  $maybe_empty Whether the post should be considered "empty".
     * @param array $postarr     Array of post data.
     */
    if ( apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_empty_content', $maybe_empty, $postarr ) ) {
        if ( $wp_error ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'empty_content', __( 'Content, title, and excerpt are empty.' ) );
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

You can do your conditionals in the wp_insert_post_empty_content filter and return true to stop the post from being inserted.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer from @KGreene is worth a try, thanks for the input.

I've changed my strategy with it, I redirect users if they don't have a jeton so they don't even see the editor, and burn a jeton on publish in a different hook.

```
/*
*   Redirect user that doesnt have jeton, let others proceed
*   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/
*/
function handle_before_publish_post($post_id, $post, $update) {

     // Only on post creation not update (they can update with 0 jeton)
    if ($update) {
        return;
    }

    $poster_id = $post->post_author;
    $meta_jeton = get_user_meta($poster_id, 'jeton')[0];

    if ($meta_jeton > 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        wp_redirect('[my-domain]/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=[my-custom-post-type]');
    }
}
add_action('save_post_[my-custom-post-type]', 'handle_before_publish_post', 10, 3);

/*
*   Use a jeton on post creation
*   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/
*/
function handle_after_publish_post($post_id, $post) {

    // Burn jeton
    $poster_id = $post->post_author;
    $meta_jeton = get_user_meta($poster_id, 'jeton')[0];
    $new_jeton_count = $meta_jeton - 1;

    update_user_meta($poster_id, 'jeton', $new_jeton_count);
    return;
}
add_action('publish_[my-custom-post-type]', 'handle_after_publish_post', 10, 3);
```

It's not the way I wanted to do it, but it works well.

Thank you all for your time